# How do you empty out data from inactive tabs?

Tags: javascript

I am building a dashboard that will have lots of divs and javascript to process the data. I like organize my content based on tabs. When clicked on a tab, I would like display certain information processed by the javascript. Since there will be a lot of data, I would like to display only information containt in the tab and destory/empty out anything other than clicked tab:

This is the the script for the tab selection:

```
<script>
            // Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
                    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
                    // which tab is active and it's associated content
                    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

                    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
                    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
                    $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                    $active.addClass('active');
                    $content = $($active.attr('href'));

                    // Hide the remaining content
                    $links.not($active).each(function () {
                        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
                    });

                    // Bind the click event handler
                    $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
                        // Make the old tab inactive.
                        $active.removeClass('active');
                        $content.hide();

                        // Update the variables with the new link and content
                        $active = $(this);
                        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                        // Make the tab active.
                        $active.addClass('active');
                        $content.show();

                        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

this is the thml for a tabs. When I clicked on the home tab, the data in the home tab will need to be displayed. I need every other data in any other divs eptied or destroyed. How would I do this?

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>it</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>markting</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab4'>finance</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab5'>accounting</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab6'>pr</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id='tab1'>
  <div id="container">
    <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><div id="web1_cpu" class="chart" style="width:500px; height:250px;"></div></td>
                <td><div id="web2_cpu" class="chart" style="width:500px; height:250px;"></div></td>

            </tr>
            </table>
            <table align="center">

            <tr>    
                <td><div id="site1_cpu" class="chart" style="width:500px; height:250px;"></div></td>
                <td><div id="site2_cpu" class="chart" style="width:500px; height:250px;"></div></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <table align="center">

            <tr>    
                <td><div id="app1_cpu" class="chart" style="width:500px; height:250px;"></div></td>
                <td><div id="app2_cpu" class="chart" style="width:500px; height:250px;"></div></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
            </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of doing that? You' won't improve performance since you're actually adding processes, and the stuff is hidden anyway.

Comment: @isherwood, each tab will have bunch of divs and each div will have charts that will have lots of data. I like only show the data under each selected tab and I like to drop all the other data from other tabs. If I dont do this, the browser will run out of memory and crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you don't want `hide()`, but `html('')`. (Note the quotes, indicating an empty value.) This will remove all of an element's contents.

http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

See this question for more on removing nodes from memory: [Remove HTML element (DOM Node) from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758963/remove-html-element-dom-node-from-memory)

Comment: isherwood, I like to empty out and then hide. Can I do both?

Comment: Inactive tabs are already hidden. I don't understand the question.

Comment: I used .html('') versus hide but when I try to click back into the tab, now I dont see any content.

Comment: Er, yup. Isn't that what you wanted? You'll have to reload your data if you want to see it again. You can't have something in memory and not in memory at the same time.

Comment: @user1471980 that's what you asked for.  you need to repopulate the tab's content with javascript/ajax or upon tab open.